# MouseEventArgs.GetPosition not working as expected in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I would try a little Shapemoving and wrote the following Application:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="27" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBar Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" MouseUp="OnMouseUp" MouseMove="OnMouseMove">
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" />
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="50" />
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="160" />
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
  public partial class MainWindow
  {
    private UIElement SelectedObject { get; set; }
    private bool captureMouse;
    private Point diffPosition;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedObject = e.Source as UIElement;
        if (SelectedObject != null)
        {
            captureMouse = SelectedObject.CaptureMouse();
            diffPosition = e.GetPosition(SelectedObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (captureMouse)
        {
            SelectedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
        SelectedObject = null;
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedObject != null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(SelectedObject, e.GetPosition(this).X - diffPosition.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(SelectedObject, e.GetPosition(this).Y - diffPosition.Y);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I thought getting the `diffPosition` of the Click-Point in `OnMouseDown` with `GetPosition` relative to `SelectedObject` save me a few lines of code, but the height of the Toolbar is added. So my Y-Coordinate is 27 pixel more than I expected. If I delete the Toolbar, all works well.
What do I have to do to get the correct offset with the Toolbar in the Form?

I know it's just a little mistake, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your drawing area:

```
 <Canvas Grid.Row="1" x:Name="drawingArea" ...>
    ...
 </Canvas>
```

and compare positions with drawingArea's.

```
e.GetPosition(this.drawingArea)
```

This way you don't need to worry about layout changes and etc.

Comment: So in `OnMouseDown` I call `GetPosition(SelectedObject)` and in `OnMouseMove` I use `GetPosition(this.drawingArea)`?